# Adding a tab to the node edit form in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have added a tab to the node edit form in Drupal 7 like this (code snippet from `hook_menu` implementation, irrelevant lines removed):

```
'node/%/products' => array(
  'title' => t('Products'),
  'page callback' => 'some_function',
  'page arguments' => array(
    1
  ),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
)
```

The tab shows up and works, however, the page is shown in the site's default theme, not in the admin theme. Also the other tabs are missing from the page that is displayed.

I tried fixing this by including this inside an implementation of `hook_admin_paths`, but it didn't make a difference:

```
return array(
    'node/%/products' => TRUE,
);
```

How can I enforce my page to show in the admin theme and display the other tabs for the node edit form (such as "Edit", "Revisions" etc.) ?

---

EDIT: The box *Use the administration theme when editing or creating content* at `admin/appearance` is ticked, and system-defined pages such as `node/%/edit` display in the admin theme, but my new page does not.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what I was doing wrong. In `hook_menu` *%* is used to denote an argument; in `hook_admin_paths`, these have to be replaced by asterisks. The following change to my implementation of `hook_admin_paths` solved it:

```
return array(
    'node/*/products' => TRUE,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

On /admin/appearance page, at the bottom of the page where you set the administration menu,  check the value of the tickbox "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content".

Comment: Thanks but that box is ticked. Pages such as `node/%/edit` are shown using the administration theme. My new page `node/%/products`, however, is not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved with the following `hook_menu` :

```
<?php
function <mymodulename>_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $output['node/%node/mypath'] = array(
    'title' => t('Title'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'page arguments' => array('node', 1),
    'page callback' => 'callback_function',
    'theme callback' => 'variable_get',
    'theme arguments' => array('admin_theme'),
  )
}

function callback_function() {
  return 'My New Page.';
}
```

I think you need to have `%node` inside the path because that's the right way to "auto load" the node (Drupal take care of this) and pass it as an argument to `callback_function` where you can use the loaded node.